# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter doesn't override onDataChanged

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

If my database is still loading, then show loading dialog. That what I want to make my chatapp works. I found out that my problem will solve by overriding `onDataChanged()` in my `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` like this code below

```
new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(...) {

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(...) {...}

@Override
protected void onDataChanged() {

  }

};
```

but the problem is I can't override the `onDataChanged()` to my Adapter. 
How can i fix this problem? please see my Screenshot below.

[image]

**UPDATED:**
This is my whole code related to my problem (other codes are not necessary to post).

```
    public void btn_discussion() {
        FRRA  = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(
                Message.class,
                R.layout.discussion_q_and_answer,
                ActivityDiscussion.MessageViewHolder.class,
                MyDatabase
        ) {

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ActivityDiscussion.MessageViewHolder viewHolder, Message model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setContent(model.getContent());
                viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                viewHolder.setTime(myConstructor.LongToDate(model.getTime()));
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDataChanged() {
                //Write something here
            }

        };
        msgList.setAdapter(FRRA);
        msgList.smoothScrollToPosition(FRRA.getItemCount());
    }
```

**RecyclerView.ViewHolder**

```
  public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    View view;
    public MessageViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.view = itemView;
    }

    private void setContent(String content) {

        TextView msg  = view.findViewById(R.id.comment);
        msg.setText(content);
    }

    private void setUsername(String username) {

        TextView msg  = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_user);
        msg.setText(username);
    }

    private void setTime(String time) {

        TextView msg  = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        msg.setText(time);
    }
}
```

Getter and Setter
**Message.java**

```
public class Message {
   private String content;
   private String Username;
   private String time;
   public Message() {}
   public Message(String mcontent, String musername, String mtime) {
        this.content = mcontent;
        this.Username = musername;
        this.time = mtime;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String message) {
        this.content = message;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return Username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String Username) {
        this.Username = Username;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

}
```

Comment: show us your whole code (adapter)

Comment: Thanks Mr. @WaleedAsim. Please see my updated post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an older version of `firebaseui` and in the older versions `onDataChanged` was not in the override methods. You can see that by clicking <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>INS</kbd> to see all override methods belonging to this class.

You need to use the latest one which is this:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.1.1'
```

and then you can use `onDataChanged` and other methods. When you upgrade you will have to use `FirebaseRecyclerOptions` also, for more info check this guide here:

[FirebaseUI for Realtime Database](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I change the version of firebaseui other dependencies turn to red. The hint says that `All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 11.6.2, 11.0.4. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.6.2 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4`

Comment: let me fix this first and I will accept your answer as correct after this. :-)

Comment: Finally it's confirmed that your answer is correct.. thanks for your help Mr. @Peter Haddad.

Comment: @basaya no problem,  happy coding!